# Merge rows into one by changing column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Table like this:

Students:

```
ID|NAME  |FOOD |Score  
1 |FRED  |Apple|23  
1 |FRED  |Pear |50  
2 |HENRY |BERRY|20  
3 |Alex  |Apple|40
```

What I want to do is to change the `FOOD` to **'MIXED'** for all students eat **more than 1** different `FOOD`. So the result would look like this:

```
ID|NAME  |FOOD |Score   
1 |FRED  |MIXED|73  
2 |HENRY |BERRY|20  
3 |Alex  |Apple|40
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `iif` with `count` condition:

```
select [ID], 
       [NAME], 
       iif(count([FOOD]) > 1, 'MIXED', [FOOD]) as [FOOD], 
       sum([Score]) as [Score]
from [Students] 
group by [ID], 
         [NAME]
```

You should use `count(distinct [FOOD])` in case `FOOD` entries can be repeated for the same `ID` and `NAME`.

Comment: Even though SQLChao and Grantly's answers worked as well. I used this and Potashin answered first.

Answer (score 1):

Using GROUP BY could get want you want.  This is a neat little trick to see if 'different values' are in more than one row

Try this on your data

```
SELECT
  ID
  ,NAME
  ,CASE 
        WHEN MIN(FOOD) <> MAX(FOOD) 
        THEN 'MIXED' ELSE [FOOD] 
   END AS FOOD
  ,SUM(Score) AS Score
GROUP BY 
  ID
  ,NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution using `case`

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/CARN67680)**

```
   SELECT
        id
      , name
      , CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 1 THEN 'MIXED' ELSE MAX(FOOD) END AS Food
      , SUM(Score) AS Score
    FROM dbo.students
    GROUP BY id, name
    ORDER BY id
```